# Error while creation of queue in WebSphere MQ for z/OS

Tags: ibm-mq, zos

The problem is regarding IBM z/OS and WebSphere MQ.
The task at hand is to create(define) a reply queue for WebSphere MQ. 
This is the main WebSphere terminal:

[IBM Websphere MQ for z/OS - Main Menu](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-INNHORciFjE/Up-GccNtvDI/AAAAAAAAK9M/-_c2W6fNNoc/s640/Capture%2520%2528640x365%2529.jpg)[1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqsaw.doc/za10550_.htm)

The reply queue is to be defined with all the properties of another predefined queue named `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE`. It has to be named `<userid>.REPLY`, where `<userid>` is my mainframe ID. According to my comprehension, the `2. Define like` **Action** has to be used to define a new object(queue in our case) based on an existing one. The **Object type** field can have either `QUEUE` or `QLOCAL` value.

As it is documented in the [IBM-Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqsaw.doc/za10550_.htm), **Name** should hold the queue on whose attributes the new queue is to be defined; so **Name** gets `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE`. **Disposition** is best declared `A`. **Connect name** is the name of the queue manager: `CSQ1`. The **Target Queue Manager** and **Action queue manager** is same as the **Connect name**.

[Main Menu with entered fields](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-JAwKnmJoNqY/Up-Gc02CoaI/AAAAAAAAK9Q/xjFVFr1iToI/s640/Capture%2520%2528640x366%2529.jpg)[2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqsao.doc/zm17440_.htm)

These settings don't work and an error pops up:

```
--- CSQO014E MQOPEN of SYSTEM.COMMAND.INPUT unsuccessful. Reason code = 2035. ---
```

Referring [to this site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqsao.doc/zm17440_.htm), I concluded that the reason for error maybe any of the two possibilities:

- Insufficient storage, or
- Authorization issues.

I raised these these concerns at the official IBM developer works community, and it was assured that if there were any technical issues they would get back to me. But no reply followed so that made me think if I were somehow at fault. So I tried almost all possible combinations of the available options and values, but every time one or the other error followed.

Your help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is pretty self explanatory.  If you do not know what reason code 2035 (not authorized) is, did you look in the MQ Messages manual?

Are you the MQAdmin or just some user trying to define a queue?  Because only the MQAdmin should be defining queues (or any other MQ objects).  If you are not the MQAdmin then ask your MQAdmin to define the required queue.